# Will the comment and spaces affect the website SVELTE

Tags: comments, svelte, space, sveltekit

Its my first time using a framework and I currrently learning creating a website using svelte.

will svelte delete the comment and spaces when compiling? or not?

I have written and added many comments and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

SvelteKit uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) which minifies the code for the production build, removing anything unnecessary like regular comments and spaces in code.